# TypeError: string indices must be integers - Cleaning my text

Tags: python, function, twitter

Trying to clean the tweets with this function:

```
class PreProcessTweets:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation) + ['AT_USER','URL'])

    def processTweets(self, list_of_tweets):
        processedTweets=[]
        for tweet in list_of_tweets:
            processedTweets.append((self._processTweet(tweet["Text"])))
        return processedTweets

    def _processTweet(self, tweet):
        tweet = tweet.lower() # convert text to lower-case
        tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))', 'URL', tweet) # remove URLs
        tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', tweet) # remove usernames
        tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet) # remove the # in #hashtag
        tweet = word_tokenize(tweet) # remove repeated characters (helloooooooo into hello)
        return [word for word in tweet if word not in self._stopwords]
```

And when I want to use it:

```
preprocessedTestSet = tweetProcessor.processTweets(tweet)
```

I received this output

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please update your question with the full Traceback. btw what is `tweetProcessor`?

Comment: I suppose your tweet is string, and you address to it like tweet["Text"] - this raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tweet` is a string. You should pass it as is. You've used `tweet["Text"]` which is an illegal operation on a string since the index must be an integer.

```
def processTweets(self, list_of_tweets):
    processedTweets=[]
    for tweet in list_of_tweets:
        processedTweets.append(self._processTweet(tweet))
    return processedTweets
```

Or more Pythonic:

```
def processTweets(self, list_of_tweets):
    return [self._processTweet(tweet) for tweet in list_of_tweets]
```

Notes:

You probably forgot to use raw strings (`r""`) in some of your regex.